# Error: cannot find symbol compiling (elementary java)

Tags: java

I'm working on a programming project for my intro class. I have a code that I'm trying to compile, but I'm having a hard time getting it to work after I added the PrintWriter. All was running well until I tried to print to a text file. Can someone help me figure out how to get it to run?
(Also, if you find any errors in my logic/layout/whatever, try to contain it! I still want to debug the program myself, I just can't do that until it runs :)

Attempt: (so far)

```
import java.util.Scanner; //import scanner
import java.util.Random; //import randomizer
import java.io.*; //needed for throws clause

public class randomLottery
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String fullName;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );

        //so we can generate random numbers
        Random rand = new Random();

        //declare a constant number of numbers
        final int LOTTERY_NUMBERS = 5;

        //Retrieve names
        System.out.print("Please enter a first and last name for lottery "
                         + "entry (type 'quit' to end): ");
        fullName = keyboard.nextLine();

        while(!fullName.contains(" "))
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter BOTH a first and last name." 
                             + " Try Again: ");
            fullName = keyboard.nextLine();
        }   

        while(!fullName.contains("quit"))
        {
            //separate first/last name
            String[] parts = fullName.split(" ");
            String firstName = parts[0];    
            String lastName = parts[1];

            //Open the file
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("LotteryEntrants.txt");

            //Print the name onto the file
            outputFile.print(lastName + ", " + firstName + ": ");

            int number;
            for (number = 1; number <= LOTTERY_NUMBERS; number++)
            {
                if (number == LOTTERY_NUMBERS)
                {
                    int lotteryNumber = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
                    outputFile.println(lotteryNumber);
                }
                else
                {
                    int lotteryNumber = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
                    outputFile.print(lotteryNumber + ", ");
                }
            }

            //get the next name
            System.out.print("Please enter BOTH a first and last name." 
                              + " Try Again: ");
            fullName = keyboard.nextLine(); 
        }

        //Winning Lottery Numbers
        outputFile.print("The winning numbers are: ");

        int winning;
        for (winning = 1; winning <= LOTTERY_NUMBERS; winning++)
        {
            if (winning == LOTTERY_NUMBERS)
                {
                    int lotteryNumber = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
                    outputFile.print(lotteryNumber);
                }
            else
                {
                    int lotteryNumber = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
                    outputFile.print(lotteryNumber + ", ");
                }
        }
    outputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: put only what is relevant here. not everything.

Comment: Don't think everyone will have patience to read this long post. Just ask your question in clear and concise way. Remove unnecessary details

Comment: All this text, yet you didn't post the relevant thing: the exact and complete error you get from the compiler, and the line it refers to.

Comment: Well, I didn't read all of this (very boring) spec for an (even more boring) programming exercise.

Answer (score 1):

```
PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("LotteryEntrants.txt");
```

Should be outside (before) the while loop.  Having it inside the loop means it is not in the scope of your other uses of outputFile after the while loop.

Comment: These unexplained downvotes... Self-righteous anonymous SO lurkers.

Comment: I find that this answer is useful. I would have left upvoting/accepting to the OP, but I feel that I should compensate the downvote.